# Custom Authorize in Asp.Net Core Web Api

Tags: api, .net-core, authorization

I need help to the follow issue:

Each endpoint of my API is decorated with the "Authorize" attribute, where I indicate the claim or the necessary claims to access the endpoint. However, the same user can have a considerable amount of claims and these claims will be stored in the database. So with every request in my API, I need to intercept this request, identify the user, query the database to see if it has the required claims, and return, providing or denying access to the requested endpoint. Most of the implementations that I saw on the internet, pass the claims in the code itself, in a static way, and that does not meet me.
I tried to implement some custom filters, but I was not successful either.

Could someone help me solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recomended you to use JWT Authorization.

It's easy to implement and also secure.

In this article you have an example with how to do it. I hope that's help you.

https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-webapi-best-practices/#jwt

Comment: https://medium.com/@ozgurgul/asp-net-core-2-0-webapi-jwt-authentication-with-identity-mysql-3698eeba6ff8

Here is a complete example.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll try this!